# VB.net Webform Gridview with checkbox DataControlRowType

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

VB.net webform pulling data from Sql database to gridview.

I have two Bit Columns Rush and Normal - In the code behind if Rush is Checked then the row cells turn Red and Normal turns blue.

The problem I have is the bit is True or False not having much luck converting them to Integer or Int32.

Here is a code I am working with, this code turn all rows blue , if cell 7 not equal to 1.

If I go to Rush cell(10) error input string not in correct format.

Question is how to convert bit from True/false to 1/0 or correct format.

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim sh As String = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells(7).Text)

        For Each cell As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
            If sh = 1 Then
                cell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            Else
                cell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Blue

            End If

        Next


    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: can you please post code of your aspx page over here

Comment: Status form , or Insert form , also how to add more code on this page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it here , instead of fighting the Boolean , I decided to
change the cells to Integer. Please check over and let me know your thoughts.
It works, Rush orders are red and normal are blue ..

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)


    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim Chkb As Integer = (e.Row.DataItem(10))

        For Each cell As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
            If Chkb = -1 Then
                cell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            Else
                cell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Blue

            End If

        Next


    End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why converting to an integer, when you are having a bit column, try with the below code.

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    Dim sh As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.Cells(7).Text)
    For Each cell As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
        If sh Then
            cell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        Else
            cell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Blue
        End If
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Throws error string not recognized as valid Boolean, That what I keep running into